# Menu fragment class not being called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I wish control my menu through a Fragment in order to minimise code
duplication. The problem I have is that the activity class receives the call when debugging, but it does not continue to the `Fragment` class. Classes shown below.

I thought that the Fragment 'participates' in the layout lifecycle
when inheriting from Fragment. What am I missing here?

## SomeActivity.java

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().show();
        setContentView(R.layout.a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void chooseLanguage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

## MenuFragment.java

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
    }

    public void startActivity(Class classs) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), classs);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.a:
                startActivity(AActivity.class);
                return true;
            case R.id.b:
                startActivity(BActivity.class);
                return true;
            case R.id.c:
                startActivity(CActivity.class);
                return true;
            case R.id.d:
                startActivity(DActivity.class);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution consists of

Adding the Fragment in the Activity's `onCreate`

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(new MenuFragment(), "Menu fragment").commit();`

Then `onOptionsItemSelected` in the Activity should return false as according to the documentation

`boolean Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, true to consume it here.`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)

Answer (score 0):

From documentioned of [onCreateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) of `Activity`:

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

So make sure to return true instead of

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not that the menu is not being displayed. But when I press a menu option, the Fragment's implementation is not being called.

Comment: You are inflating same file `R.menu.main` from `Activity` as well as `Fragment`. May be thats causing issue. If you don't want to any thing in `onOptionsItemSelected()` in `Activity` then don't inflate it.